# Image not working when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When you click a navigation item at the top of the screen, a blank div pops up with a huge "x" image that when clicked, the x image is suppose to close the blank div and everything else. For "jobs, contact, press, and legal" it doesn't work when clicked but for "support" it works perfectly. I put the code side by side to see errors, copy the support code and paste for others... basically everything imaginable for 1-2hours. I found a glitch that when you open the "support" first then close it out and open another one, the x image works but I don't know why. Here is my html and the rest of the code will be uploaded to codeine

demo: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dvzgrY

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="magicstyle.css">
        <body>
            <!-- Section for Jobs Popup -->
            <div id="job-popup">
                <div class="x-div1"><img class="x-icon1" id="fadeX1" src="Pictures/web%20x%20icon%20white.png"></div>
                <div id="job-content"> 
                    <h1 id="jobWords"></h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Section for Contact Popup -->
            <div id="contact-popup">
                <div class="x-div2"><img class="x-icon2" id="fadeX2" src="Pictures/web%20x%20icon%20white.png"></div>
                <div id="contact-content">
                    <h1 id="contactWords"></h1>
                </div>
            </div>  
            <!-- Section for Press Popu -->
             <div id="press-popup">
                <div class="x-div3"><img class="x-icon3" id="fadeX3" src="Pictures/web%20x%20icon%20white.png"></div>
                <div id="press-content"> 
                    <h1 id="pressWords"></h1>  
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="legal-popup">
                <div class="x-div4"><img class="x-icon4" id="fadeX4" src="Pictures/web%20x%20icon%20white.png"></div>
                <div id="legal-content">
                    <h1 id="legalWords"></h1>
                </div>             
            </div> 
            <div id="support-popup">
                <div class="x-div5"><img class="x-icon5" id="fadeX5" src="Pictures/web%20x%20icon%20white.png"></div>
                <div id="support-content">                   
                    <h1 id="supportWords"></h1>                    
                </div>             
            </div>         
            <div id="top-bar">
                <a class="burger-nav"></a>
                <div id="nav-menu">
                    <span id="job">Jobs</span>
                    <span id="contact">Contact</span>
                    <span id="press">Press</span>
                    <span id="legal">Legal</span>
                    <span id="support">Support</span>                       
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="name-div">
                    <h1 id="name">Open Touch</h1>
                </div>
                <ul class="bubbles">              
                    <li id="firstCircle"></li>
                    <li id="secondCircle"></li>
                    <li id="thirdCircle"></li>
                    <li id="fourthCircle"></li>
                    <li id="fifthCircle"></li>
                    <li id="sixthCircle"></li>             
                </ul>
            </div>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated :D

Comment: your pencode page is not found, check it.

Comment: Opps D: Fixed :D Thank you

Comment: Your code **appears** to work fine, though it is hard to tell. Could you please update your pen so that it uses absolute URLs, and clearly demonstrates the problem in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks :)

Comment: your HTML code is so strange, why did you put body tag inside head tag?

Comment: Too be honest guys, I am new to this so forgive me D:

Comment: @ObsidianAge I am not sure why it looks like that on code pen

Comment: @thatoneguy90 Because you are using relative URLs. The files are relative to folders on your computer. CodePen doesn't have a folder called `Pictures` with a file called `web x icon white.png` in it. Files that exist on the web shouldn't really have spaces in them for that matter -- although they get converted to `%20`, it's better to either use a hyphen or underscore. Your code also has some invalid markup (like `<body>` inside `<head>`), so you may want to run it through a validator: https://validator.w3.org/ :)

Comment: Ohh ok well I searched up how to do absolute URLS but I couldn't find anything. I removed the "pictures" park and same thing". I am uploading to the website thank you

Comment: I did every thing it said to do @ObsidianAge and my problem is still here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that all your popup containers (job-popup, contact-popup, etc) are positioned absolutely at the same location with the same z-index. Since the support-popup is last in your html, it's hiding all the popup containers underneath it. You are never actually clicking on the other x-icons (only on the top support one), and therefore, the click handlers are not getting triggered.

For a quick fix, you could update the z-index, in your nav click handlers. For example:

```
$("#job").click(function() {
    $("#job-popup").fadeIn(300);
    $("#job-popup").css({'z-index': 15});
    $("#job-content").fadeIn(300); 
    $("#jobWords").fadeIn(300); 
    $(".x-icon1").fadeIn(300); 
    $("#name").fadeOut(300); 
    $("#container").css("-webkit-filter", "blur(10px)");
}
```

and then move it back down here

```
 $(".x-icon1").click(function() {
     $("#job-popup").fadeOut(); 
     $("#job-popup").css({'z-index': 10});
     $("#job-content").fadeOut(); 
     $("#jobWords").fadeOut(); 
     $(".x-icon1").fadeOut();  
     $("#name").fadeIn();  
     $("#container").css("-webkit-filter", "blur(0px)");
}
```

and then replicate this for all your click handlers.

But you should also consider refactoring your html/css, since the structure is incorrect (body within head, for example), and a lot of the css is probably unnecessary.

Comment: thank you sooo much :D And oohooooo I see I knew something was up with the z-index. I fixed the body and head thing. And which code is unnecessary ?

Comment: Np :) Almost your entire layout is done using position absolute. That is taking all the elements out of the default DOM flow, and then elements are also unaware of any other elements around them. Your layout will be much more flexible if you keep everything within the normal flow and you wont need to add specific positioning (top, right, bottom, left) to each element.

Comment: I  mean if I don't add the position stuff, it won't go where I need it